# Is there any reason that a jpg Image would look the same (to the human eye) but have different actually binary data when rendered in x32 vs x64

Tags: c#, image, 64-bit

I have a regression test that essentially loads an image and saves the image, using Image.Save, my problem is that the binary of the image is different when it is saved on the x32 bit system versus the x64 bit system, but this is only a problem the computer would catch. The image is the correct size, looks correct etc but for some reason the binary is different. Could it also be related to the processor that is used to render the image?

Comment: Please specify language, library used, its version and target OS. I think you should submit regression reports to the library developers, rather than on SO.

Comment: That's absolultely to be expected. JPEG uses a lossy compression scheme, and small *permissible* differences in floating point math between processors can result in tiny differences in the output. I'd use a lossless compression scheme if you require that sort of repeatability.

Comment: Are you comparing the binary data of the image or just the file size in bytes?

Comment: Eric thank you that makes total sense.. actually kind of seems like a dumb question now.

Comment: Just to add to what Eric said, can you try saving the data in PNG format (if you can modify the code) and look for differences?